I need to hammer a few last nails on my typing productivity solving the problems that I am facing with keyd. Can you help me out?
So the problems with keyd that need to be address so that I can have my peak typing efficiency are:

Enabling context menu key as right super when pressed and as normal context menu key when clicked. To do that, I tried menu=overload(super,menu). It didn't work. Then I looked into the output of keyd listkeys and changed the command to menu=overload(rightmeta,menu). If I try to use the menu key as control key instead of super or rightmeta then it works perfectly fine. But control key is not missing on the right side of my space key, super/meta key is missing.

I can do mouse left/right/middle click via keyd. But I can't do mouse scroll via keyd. Keyd covered almost every thing. It must have something that covers mouse scrolling too. I read the man page and can't find anything in this regard. In the output of keyd list-keys there are keys named 1.leftmouse 2.rightmouse 3.middlemouse 4.mouse1 5.mouse2. But the keys mouse1, and mouse2 do not simulate mouse-scroll up/down. I tried those. They didn't give me the mouse scrolling effect. I didn't understand what those keys are for either. It would be great if any of you can tell me that.

Using this command xset r rate 220 25 makes my life very easy. It lets me repeat any key just after 220 milliseconds of holding it, and the key repeats itself at a rate 25/seconds. But this command doesn't persist through logout/login like any of the effects implemented by keyd does. It would be great if I could do the same thing using keyd.



Please restrict yourself to a single problem per question.

@DanielB should I split this one into to three different question or I can keep this in mind and refrain all future question to just one and one problem only,  Let me know
